# X-Ray print recognition via AForge.NET lib

Tags: .net, image-processing, image-recognition, aforge

I have quite an specific question about image recognition. I have to write a tool which recognizes objects on x-ray print, and calculates some data based on current x-ray shot. So the task basically is to reduce colors on image, then to recognize the similar by color & distance set, then I need to process the calculation.

I've never worked with an image recognition, so I wanted to ask about efficient algorithms for reducing the color palette to fixed colors amount. Estimate is quite a short one, so I basically do not have too much time for investigating the ways to deal with it. I've found AForge .NET library but still I can't reduce image colors significantly. (maybe I just don't know which filter to use).  Any libraries or algorithms for the task would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you only need to rescale your color values using `integer part` or any other chopping function.

Example in Mathematica:

[image]

Comment: You're getting a +1 just for the sample image.

Comment: @Mark I was googling for an Xray image to use in the example. Found this one and couldn't resist :)